# How to delete last N rows from a large (big) file

Tags: php, linux

Read the entire file of 500-600 MB I can not, since the data are loaded into memory, for me it's too expensive.

I read the file c file_get_content'om limit lines (conditional on 1000 lines). How can I say after that remove specific lines. Without the use of $ f = file.

Read more: I read a very large file to 1000 lines (the first 1000 lines), in its processes them, and depending on conditions, any line you want to remove, and some leave.

I can write the result in a temporary file, and if the script stops or something else, but there is no rollback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Php has the [ftruncate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ftruncate.php) function.

Edit: give the full solution.

```
$f = fopen($filename, 'r+');
$linepos = array_fill(0, $N + 1, 0);
$i = 0;
while (! feof($f)) {
    $line = fgets($f);
    if ($line !== FALSE) {
        $j = ($i + 1) % ($N + 1);
        $linepos[$j] = $linepos[$i] + strlen($line);
        $i = $j;
    }
}
ftruncate($f, $linepos[($i + 1) % ($N + 1)]);
fclose($f);
```

Comment: string have different length (

Comment: @frops Yes, you have to memorize the last `N` lines positions and `ftruncate` once you reach the end of file. I edited my answer to give you the full answer.

Comment: @kmkaplan i need to truncate the last line, no matter what its length would be, is there a way ?

Comment: @Deepanshu while this solution is overkill, it should do the trick if you use `$N = 1`.